# reshape result from mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

In my node.js app I use a mongodb with the mongoose driver. How can I reshape the result from the Modell.find() operation? If I got and example document like this:

```
{
   _id:   ObjectId(...),
   score: 14,
   time:  123
}
```

and in my find operation I want to ad a index (counter) on the results from .find() and rename the _id field. Is this possible?

If want my document stream to look something like this:

```
[{
   index:   0
   player:  ObjectId // _id field renamed to player
   score:   14,
   time:    123
},
{
   index:   1
   player:  ObjectId // _id field renamed to player
   score:   6,
   time:    321
},
...
{
   index:   N
   player:  ObjectId // _id field renamed to player
   score:   1,
   time:    456
}
]
```

I tried with

```
Modell.find({}, {player: '$_id', score: 1, time: 1})
      .exec(function(err, players) {
         ...
});
```

But the _id field is not renamed in the resulting document stream. Is this possible? And how do I create a counter of the documents in the document stream.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `.find()` method will not do this sort of renaming. For that you need the aggregation framework and the [**`$project`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) operator.

The index numbers on the document are another thing entirely though, and even though I cannot see why you would need this as the "array" is already accesible by those "index" values, you would change the result "after" it was retrieved from the server.

```
Model.aggregate(
    [
        { "$project": {
            "_id": 0,
            "player": "$_id",
            "score": 1,
            "time": 1,
        }},
    ],
    function(err,results) {
        if (err) throw err;

        results = results.map(function(x,index) { x.index = index; return x; });
        console.log(results);
    }
);
```

Actually you could do the whole thing with map if you just want to return whole results:

```
Model.find({},function(err,result) {
    if (err) throw err;

    results = results.map(function(x,index) { 
        x.index = index;
        x.player = x._id;
        delete x._id;
        return x; 
    });

    console.log(results);
});
```

Comment: Where do I put my search query if I need one in the aggregate? The same as Model.find( {score: 10} ) ...

Comment: See [`$match`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) in the documentation. Really you can just use find even and reshape the whole result. You don't seen to be worried about iterating a cursor here.